# Pass message to Apple Watch using MMWormhole

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm developing an Apple Watch App, and I need to notify the watch when certain changes occur in the parent application. I'm using the MMWormhole library found on GitHub, but I'm having trouble passing messages from the phone to the watch. Here is my code, do you have any ideas on why this is happening?

My main viewController code looks like this

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.wormhole = [[MMWormhole alloc] initWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"com.mycompany.myapp"
                                                         optionalDirectory:@"wormhole"];

    NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Test String"];


    [self.wormhole passMessageObject:@{@"string" : myString}
                      identifier:@"messageIdentifier"];
```

My `InterfaceController` from my `WatchkitExtension` looks like this:

InterfaceController.m

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    // Initialize the wormhole
    self.wormhole = [[MMWormhole alloc] initWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"com.mycompany.myapp"
                                                         optionalDirectory:@"wormhole"];

    // Obtain an initial value for the selection message from the wormhole
    id messageObject = [self.wormhole messageWithIdentifier:@"messageIdentifier"];

    NSString *string = [messageObject valueForKey:@"string"];

    if (string != nil) {
        NSLog(string);
        [myLabel setText:string];
    }

    // Listen for changes to the selection message. The selection message contains a string value
    // identified by the selectionString key. Note that the type of the key is included in the
    // name of the key.
    [self.wormhole listenForMessageWithIdentifier:@"messageIdentifier" listener:^(id messageObject) {

        NSString *string = [messageObject valueForKey:@"string"];

        if (string != nil) {
            [self.myLabel setText:string];
        }
    }];                                    
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could it be because your listener is looking for a key called `locationString` instead of `string`? Otherwise, this looks correct.

Comment: Are both the phone and the watch open at the same time? Under the capabilities section of your app, is the app group throwing any sort of errors?

Comment: Sorry, i edited the post, because my key was called "locationString" in my code, but i changed it to make it easier for people to understand on StackOverflow. I corrected it in the post, and in my code, although is alright, its not working either.

Comment: Yes, both apps are open at the same time, and no, i don't have any errors on my log, its like its not saving in app groups the way it should.

Comment: Isn't better to use the new API instead of MMWormHole? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:

Comment: Im using the API, but for different purposes. The problem is that i don't know how to set up the app so the watch is listening for changes on my app ViewController. I want to send messages to the apple watch via my watckitExtension InterfaceController, so the message that im sending arrives in real time and it feels like is being pushed.

Comment: I met the same problem as you. Do you find the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Is `"com.mycompany.myapp"` the real value you use in the app? Because group identifiers have to start with `group.`.

If you use a wrong group identifier everything fails because the `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier` call inside MMWormhole returns nil. Unfortunately the developers of MMWormhole didn't do any checks or asserts to make sure that the shared group identifier is correct.

So I would recommend to stop concentrating on MMWormhole for a minute. Instead add this code early in your code (e.g. `applicationDidFinishLaunching`) to verify that your container identifier is correct:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSURL *appGroupContainer = [fileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.mycompany.myapp"];
if (!appGroupContainer) {
    NSLog(@"group identifier incorrect, or app groups not setup correctly");
}
```

This will tell you if your app group setup is incorrect.

I'm not sure how far you are into setting up app groups, but you have to use the group identifier you used in the App Groups capabilities section of your project.

[image]

Comment: I have tried changing it from group.com.mycompany.myapp to com.mycompany.myapp and it doesn't work either way. But thank you for your post, now i can check the name of the group and store it in a variable to use it when its convenient. On the upside, im sure that te problem its not on the appgroup name, and i can focus somewhere else.

Comment: So you actually get the container in the code I posted?

Comment: Yes, and when i use "group.com.mycompany.myapp", it doesnt whow the NSLog, so im using the groupIdentifier correctly. Thanks

Comment: But i still cannot send messages from the app to the WatchkitExtension

Comment: Did you try running all the test in MMWormholeTests.m, based on your app group? Are all passed ? I just download and tried the MMWormhole with my app group, it seems communicating fine with watch and app.

Comment: Are we supposed to use one wormhole per view controller, or one wormhole per app?